Define a specific policy in the domain controller gpo
I am defining a series of special policies in my domain controller, I wanted the user not to have admin access, but to be able to share the folder on the network for other users.
I even set the user’s local access to admin and closed the installation access through gpo, but it didn’t work

To allow a user to share folders on the network without giving them full admin access, configure a custom GPO. In the Group Policy Management Editor, navigate to User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > File Explorer and enable the policy Prevent users from sharing files within their profile. Then, set the user's local group membership to Power Users instead of Administrators. Ensure they have the necessary permissions to manage shared folders by adjusting the security settings on the folder itself. This should allow them to share folders without full admin rights.
